# how to increase the height of div using css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-grid

I am using **css grid** in my demo application.My application is working fine when I have small **heading** or **small title**  **(h2)**.

but when The title is big my application works behave buggy or not as expected output  .

here is my code

https://codepen.io/naveen-1234/pen/zYzKqQW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<head>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 40px);
        }

        .one {
            grid-column: 2/5;
            grid-row: 2/5;
            background-color: #ee0
        }

        .two {
            grid-column: 4/8;
            grid-row: 3/8;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000
        }

        .header_container {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            min-height: 50px

        }

        .header_container h2 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">Two
        <div class="header_container">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**First case** (which is working fine) when tile is small[image]

**Case two** when Title is big.it show like this which is wrong. It overlap the `Two` text and not increase the container.
[image]

**Expected output.**

1. When Title text increase both black border container increase in upward direction .Inner black border and outer black border grows in upward direction.
2. It will not overlap the text **(TWO)**

Expected output screenhot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your css for **.header_container h2** like below and it should work.

```
.header_container h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: it is increasing div height in downward direction ...I want it should increase in upword direction

Comment: Can you post the expected result screen-shot?

Comment: attached expected screen shot..I am not able preble this solution

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using position absolute for the h2 heading.]

```
.header_container h2 {
/*   position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  */
  margin: 0; 
}
```

What position absolute does that it makes the element like a ghost and it is not able to take any space in the HTML flow. If you want to use absolute position use it on the parent that is on  `<div class="two">Two</div>`

If you find the answer helpful then please accept it. It lets others know that it is the correct answer.

Comment: please delete your answer not helpful .. after this it grow in downward direction

Comment: Can you explain ur question and also expected output a little better because if you want it to go upwards then it will surely overlap with the text two. U can use the image of the output.

Comment: see the attached image as a expected output